# How can I get my custom function execution address when coding?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Simple code, eg:

```
void* print_my_address() {
    printf("%p\n", .../* get the execution address of print_my_address */)
}
```

Thanks!

PS: gcc v4.7
Can I get the address by compiler?

Comment: What do you mean by "execution address" ? Your function will always have the same address (`&print_my_address`), this can't change. Or do you mean the address of the current stack frame ?

Comment: @Nbr44 Yes, function address, but how can I get it when I'm coding, before compile?

Comment: @KaiWen, It doesn't have an address before you compile.

Comment: @KaiWen you have no other way of knowing a function's address other than using `&your_function_name`.

Comment: The address does not exist in a text file that you wrote the function in. After compilation and running the address is assigned and then you can reference it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way you'd do it for any other regular variable:

```
void print_my_address() 
{
    printf("%p\n", &print_my_address);
}
```

Comment: Note that while the `&` is allowed, just like getting the address of a normal variable, it's *not* required. Also note that a pointer to a function is a different type from a normal pointer, so this isn't guaranteed to work anyway.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Do you have a reference for that? From 6.5.3.2: *The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
[] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
not declared with the register storage-class specifier.*

Comment: function pointers are not type-compatible with any other pointers (I believe C99 allows them to be compatible with `(void *)`, but I'd expect you to need to cast it when passing to `printf()`). What JerryCoffin is saying, however, is that you don't need to use the `&`, because `&print_my_address` is completely equivalent to `print_my_address` in pointer context.

Comment: @Yuushi: C99, §6.3.2.1/4: "Except when it is the
operand of the sizeof operator) or the unary & operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’." As far as incompatibility goes (§7.19.6.1): "p The argument shall be a pointer to void."

Comment: @Yuushi: To finish that up (§6.5.2.2/6): "If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (, ...) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined." Default promotions don't include a promotion from pointer to function to pointer to void.

Comment: POSIX requires pointers to functions to be the same size as pointers to data; C (none of C89, C99 or C11) does not require function pointers to be the same size as data pointers.